# CPU fault after quick power cycle

Tags: motherboard, amd-ryzen

I have a Ryzen 5800X slotted in an Asus TUF gaming B550 plus motherboard.

I have noticed that if I power the computer on and off quickly enough the motherboard stops posting, and the motherboard stalls with the red CPU fault light on.

When it gets in this state the only way I have been able to resolve it is to take off the heatsink and reseat the CPU.  Literally just taking the CPU out and putting it back in fixes it, and the CPU works perfectly until I do another quick power cycle accidentally.

It's almost like a tripped fuse, and reseating it resets it.

This partially happens when I'm not paying attention and the power button on the case gets stuck down, it can also happen if I don't release the button fast enough when doing a hard reset.

This is extremely frustrating because I really don't like messing with the CPU much cause I don't want to risk bending pins (already happened once, but luckily I fixed it).

Does anyone have any idea why this happens, and if there's an easier way to reset it without reseating the CPU?

Comment: Do you have the latest BIOS installed? https://forum-en.msi.com/index.php?threads/solved-b550m-pro-vdh-wifi-5800x-cpu-debug-light-on-no-post-help.363780/

Comment: Hrm probably not.  That's a good call out

Comment: Doing a flashback bios at least got me back in without reseating the CPU, so that's a good sign.

Comment: You might want to repair or replace the the power button so it does not get stuck down.

Answer (score 0):

**AVOID doing quick power cycling**, electronics tend to BREAK by that.

The electronics engineer that created the device DID NOT EXPECT THAT TO HAPPEN, NOR PREPARE IT to allow YOU TO DO THAT!

Leave it OFF for at least 4-5 seconds, slightly more might be better.

In the same manner as memory is accessed clock cycle by clock cycle, the "power on" action of DC/DC converters (and PSUs) depend on a specific "cycle" - if you interrupt and restart this in quick succession - there is risk that unexpected and undefined situations appear; and **you do not want power feed to behave "unexpectedly"** if you wish to keep your gear in working condition.

*Note: RESET is NOT "power cycling".*

Comment: Any electronics engineer who does not prepare for input that can easily happen is not doing his job. I'd say the same for software developers, web designers, database admins, or any other professional designing for the general population.

Comment: agreed, but we live in the real world, part of my job is to handle claims where I see this a number of times per year. Now we could discuss what "easily" means in this context.

Comment: It is a tradeoff. Do you want to do it "right" or is it cheaper overall to handle a certain number of claims per year? May be cheaper for the manufacturer but annoying to the customers involved so you have to factor in consumer relations (and reviews).

Comment: That depends, cheap devices is likely to skip some portions of a reasonable design. On top of that; even a "better" design will fail under unfavorable conditions.